# 32 bit unmanaged dll in 64 bit wrapper

Tags: c#, wrapper, 32bit-64bit, dllimport

I'm creating a wrapper from loading 32-bit unmanaged dll to execute in 64-bit environment. so my approach used this [LegacyWrapper](https://github.com/CodefoundryDE/LegacyWrapper)

```
[LegacyDllImport("ste.dll")]
public interface INativeMethods : IDisposable
{
    [LegacyDllMethod(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    IIntPtr ste_init_with_environment_info(string dirLocation, string language);
}
```

I'm calling this method as below

```
public IWrapperConfig Configuration
{
    get
    {
        return _configuration ??= WrapperConfigBuilder.Create().TargetArchitecture(TargetArchitecture.X86).Build();
    }
}


using var client = WrapperProxyFactory<INativeMethods>.GetInstance(Configuration);
_steHandle = client.ste_init_with_environment_info(steHomeDirectory, SystemProperties());
```

it seems works without exception but. When I call the function, as a result, I'm getting `0x0000000000000000` which should be something like `0x0186ad58` what causes the issue?

**UPDATE**

when I see the source code of LagacyWrapper  see the serialization and deserialization as below using `System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter`

```
public void SendCallRequest(CallData callData)
{
    _formatter.Serialize(_pipe, callData);
}

public CallResult ReceiveCallResponse()
{
    CallResult callResult = (CallResult)_formatter.Deserialize(_pipe);

    if (callResult.Exception != null)
    {
        throw callResult.Exception;
    }

    return callResult;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with LegacyWrapper, so this is based on conjecture.

From the blogpost introducing Legacy wrapper:

> Since we can’t load 32bit code into our 64bit process, the idea is to create a separate executable for this task. It would somehow load a library, invoke a specific function and pass the results back to the caller.

Since your library runs in another process, returning a pointer to memory will probably not work. As far as I know there is no general way to know how much valid memory a pointer points to, so how would the wrapper know how much memory to copy? This might be possible to solve for some special cases, but I cannot find any documentation about the details of the serialization-process.

You might be able to define that the pointer should be [marshalled to a structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?view=netcore-3.1). Otherwise you might want to post an issue at the legacyWrapper project page, to clarify the documentation if nothing else.

Comment: Hi JonasH i dig in to source code and found these lines were sending and receiving messages. please have a look on updated post

Comment: the code does not give much information. If CallResult just contains a pointer then the formatter would just serialize the pointer value, not the actual object pointed to, as you would want. You would still want to marshal the pointer to a managed struct in order to serialize the object correctly.

Comment: To be honest i have no clue. do you have any code sample or article to share with me

Comment: Sorry, no. We have used a similar solution to access a  32bit library in a 64 bit process, i.e. move it to a separate process. But we did it ourselves, without the help of a library. I'm not sure if it is even possible to marshal pointers automatically, most examples I can find does it by hand. A workaround might be to create a wrapper project that calls any native methods and copies the result to simple, easy to serialize, .net objects.